# Appending Pandas DataFrames - indexing not matching

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, append

New to pandas and a simple append has me stumped. I've basically pivoted data to create an original dataframe like this:

```
df_dict['Parish_Totals'] = pd.pivot_table(df_dict['S106'], values=['AP','AS'], index=['PARISH'],columns=['Covenant Area'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)
```

This works fine, but obviously doesn't return any parishes that aren't in the dataset to begin with. Client needs a full list of parishes (with zeros where they have no value). To do this I got a list of all parishes, then compared the list to the parishes i had data for to get those parishes that aren't in the data that need to be added to it. I did this ok like this:

```
# List of zeros to populate fields for additional parishes with no data missing from pivot
zeros = [0]*10
list_of_rows_to_add = []
# List of columns to match the pivoted data
column_heads = ['PARISH', 'POS_AP',  'POS_AS', 'ED_AP', 'ED_AS', 'TH_AP', 'TH_AS', 'AH_AP', 'AH_AS', 'OT_AP', 'OT_AS']

# For every parish not featured in the pivot (with no data to display)

for parish in all_parishes:

    if parish not in df_dict['Parish_Totals'].index:
        
        # Create a list of values for a new row, starting with the parish name at position 0

        row_to_add = zeros.copy()

        row_to_add.insert(0,parish)

        # Add the new row to the list of rows to be added
        list_of_rows_to_add.append(row_to_add)
        
df_dict['Empty_Parishes'] = pd.DataFrame(list_of_rows_to_add, columns = column_heads)
        
df_dict['Empty_Parishes'].set_index('PARISH')
```

This looks ok too, and so i thought all i need to do was append the pivoted data to my zero values data.

```
df_dict['NEW'] = df_dict['Parish_Totals'].append(df_dict['Empty_Parishes'])
```

However when i do, it seems to ignore the 'PARISH' index:

[image: Mismatched indexing]

If i call index on my pivoted data i get this:

Index(['Altarnun', 'Bodmin', 'Breage', 'Bude-Stratton', 'Budock', 'Callington',
'Calstock', 'Camborne', 'Camelford', 'Cardinham',
...
'Tregony with Cuby', 'Treverbyn', 'Truro', 'Tywardreath and Par',
'Veryan', 'Wadebridge', 'Week St. Mary', 'Wendron', 'Whitstone',
'Withiel'],
dtype='object', name='PARISH', length=150)

Whereas if i call index on my 'zero' data that i'm appending, i get this:

RangeIndex(start=0, stop=62, step=1)

Similarly if i call 'columns' on the zero dataset, it includes 'PARISH', whereas on my pivoted df, 'PARISH' is not listed (presumably because it's an index).

I've spent a ridiculous amount of time trying to figure out what i expect is a pretty simple thing. Can anyone put me out of my misery? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably easier to do a `merge`

```
#create a pandas series from all_parishes
df_all_parishes =  pd.DataFrame(all_parishes, columns=['parish'])

result = df_all_parishes.merge(right=df_pivot_table, how='left').fillna(value=0)
```

you will need to change the parameters depending what you're merging on. As it will merge on columns with the same name i.e. 'parish' should be a common column. not sure if you have it as your index for you pivot table, if so you can `reset_index()` to change to a numeric range index

Comment: This was alot easier - thanks. The index issue was infuriating - could not get my head around it. Anyway this worked a treat :)